# QGIS 3.10 and QEPANET

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qepanet

I am a beginner to QGIS. I have found the QEPANET plugin to be very interesting  with a lot of features. While locating a reservoir or tank there are no problems. When working with pipes, it works well but on saving, I receive the following message: "Could not commit changes to layer pipes" and "geometry type is not compatible with the current layer."
The pipe layer was created by QEPANET. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

In the most of the cases, for me at least, is different layer type geometry. For example you marged some of the pipe and in result you make multiline geometry, but the layer you have is line geometry. Solution. Write this layer as multiline geometry.